# Ubuntu partitioning, unallocated 7.21 GiB but 1 MiB free

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to add some space to my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS partition. I shrank Windows space from Disk Management in Windows 10 and I'm trying to extend the Ubuntu part from GParted 0.30.0 in Ubuntu.

> I cannot understand why there are 7.21 GiB unallocated now but the free space which "see" the ubuntu disk is only 1 MiB.

In the similar questions I didnt find what I need to do pratically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All of your unallocated space is to the *left* of the partition. This means the entire partition (all 70 GB of it) must be *moved* to the left before it can be extended to the right.

Extending to the right can be done on-line, but moving a partition (without LVM) requires it to be unmounted – so this can only be done from a LiveCD. Download an Ubuntu ISO (any recent version), write it to a USB stick, boot the system from it and use GParted from there.

(The ext4 filesystem isn't very flexible – it expects its metadata to be at a specific location near the beginning. If GParted allowed you to just extend to the left without moving anything, the filesystem's metadata would suddenly be somewhere in the middle and couldn't be found anymore.)

Answer (score 0):

There's a key icon there in your pic.

I'll assume this means it's mounted.

Unmount it and then it'll likely allow you to *move* the partition to the left.